# ARCore – How do I change camera focus to "Auto Focus"?

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

I am trying to implement the Augmented Images example but for an object that is really close to the camera. Thus, I need the focus to be changed as the fixed focus makes the foreground object completely blurred.

I am using Java in Android Studio along with Sceneform ARCore 1.6 for this project and it would really help if some code were posted along with a solution so I can implement this.

I have tried the following, but get an error saying 'Cannot resolve symbol 'context''

```
Session session = new Session(context);
Config config = new Config(session);

config.setFocusMode(Config.FocusMode.AUTO);
session.configure(config);
```

Comment: is this code inside an activity? if it is, you could call new Session(this); From the error message, the problem probably is that you are not creating a variable assigning the context

Comment: When I try that, I get the following error for Session in Session(this):

Unhandled exceptions: com.google.ar.core.exceptions.UnavailableArcoreNotInstalledException, com.google.ar.core.exceptions.UnavailableApkTooOldException, com.google.ar.core.exceptions.UnavailableSdkTooOldException, com.google.ar.core.exceptions.UnavailableDeviceNotCompatibleException

None of these make sense as everything is installed and up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code for proper configuration:

```
Session session = new Session(context);
Config configuration = new Config(session);

if (enableAutoFocus) {
    configuration.setFocusMode(Config.FocusMode.AUTO);
} else {
    configuration.setFocusMode(Config.FocusMode.FIXED);
}

session.configure(configuration);
```

But at the time of writing this post, Google [confirms](https://www.androidpolice.com/2019/01/29/google-confirms-autofocus-not-working-in-arcore-for-several-lg-phones/) that autofocus isn't working in ARCore 1.8 for some LG models.